# How do you split json into multiple events in Logstash, where events are parts of a hash (unique)

Tags: json, logstash

I apologize if this question has been asked already, but I could not find it anywhere.

In Logstash I have json input that looks like this:

```
{
    common_field: "commonValue",
    events: {
        ID_1: {
            name: "name1",
            other_field: "value1",
            ...
        },
        ID_2: {
            name: "name2",
            other_field: "value2",
            ...
        },
        ID_3: {
            name: "name3",
            other_field: "value3",
            ...
        },
        ID_4: {
            name: "name4",
            other_field: "value4",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way in logstash to create separate events for each "ID"? Logstash will not allow me to split on "events" and I get a tag: `[0] "_split_type_failure"`. Any guidance would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ID_1/ID_2/ID_3 are always the same, you can use the `clone` filter to clone the event and and then remove the other fields on the clones.  If they aren't, as far as I know, the only way to do it is with a custom plugin.

The last time I checked (several years ago), then mechanism that `clone` uses (`yield`) isn't available to a ruby filter.

To use clone, you'd do this:

```
clone {
  clones => ["ID_1","ID_2"..,"ID_n"]
}
if [type] == "ID_1" {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["[events][ID_2]","[events][ID_3]",..."[events][ID_n]"]
    rename => {
        "[events][ID_1][name]" => "name",
        "[events][ID_1][other_field]" => "other_field"
    }
  }
} else if [type] == "ID_2" {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["[events][ID_1]","[events][ID_3]",..."[events][ID_n]"]
    rename => {
        "[events][ID_2][name]" => "name",
        "[events][ID_2][other_field]" => "other_field"
    }
  }
} ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to use the ruby filter as well and it wasn't working. I will try the clone filter!

Comment: Thanks for the help again. So when I use the clone filter, each cloned event that I make has the field "events" which has all of the IDs and their fields. How do I remove the data out of the "events" field that I don't want, and make the data that I do want into their own fields for each event?

Comment: A quick follow up question. What would be the best way to dynamically get the IDs and clone them if they aren't always the same? I have used ruby to get them into an array field, but the clone filter does not let me use that array as input for clones like this: `clones => [arrayField]`. No new clones are created. Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: In my answer, I put "if you know what the IDs are"... i don't know of a way to dynamically pass something like that to clones... i don't think that's possible because the clones plugin gets that array of clones from the config file at startup.  If you want to dynamically clone based on the fields, you're likely going to need to write your own plugin for it

Comment: I went ahead and forked the clone filter and make the changes that would be needed to do it dynamically: https://github.com/alcanzar/logstash-filter-clone -- you'd use `clone { clone_array_name => "clones" }` where `clones` is the event field that has the list of clones you want to create

Comment: And I submitted a pull-request so that maybe it'll get included in a future release

Answer (score 0):

What about converting the hash into an array, and then split the array?

I would do something like

```
ruby { code => "event.set('events_array', event.get('events').to_a) "}
split {field => "events_array"
       target => "new_object"
      }
```